# Compartilhar meu resultado

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde, criei um aplicativo de arbitragem de futebol... e procurei na internet como compartilhar o resultado encontrei essa forma(um membro aqui do stackoverflow em Português)

```
String message = "Text I want to share.";
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));
```

só que a mensagem gravada seria essa `String message = "Text I want to share.";`

como que faria para aparecer a mensagem em `String` que está no Banco de dados?

Tentei dessa forma e não deu certo:

```
 String message = Esporte;
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));
```

Meu banco de dados (get e set):

```
package Base;

public class Esporte {

    private int id;
    private String nomeTimeUm;
    private String nomeTimeDois;
    private String jogadores;
    private int valorUm;
    private int valorDois;

    public Esporte(){}

    public Esporte(int id, String nomeTimeUm, String nomeTimeDois, String jogadores, int valorUm, int valorDois){
        this.id = id;
        this.nomeTimeUm = nomeTimeUm;
        this.nomeTimeDois = nomeTimeDois;
        this.jogadores = jogadores;
        this.valorUm = valorUm;
        this.valorDois = valorDois;
    }

    public int getId(){return id;}

    public void setId(int id){this.id = id;}

    public String getNomeTimeUm(){return nomeTimeUm;}

    public void setNomeTimeUm(String nomeTimeUm){this.nomeTimeUm = nomeTimeUm;}

    public String getNomeTimeDois(){return nomeTimeDois;}

    public void setNomeTimeDois(String nomeTimeDois){this.nomeTimeDois = nomeTimeDois;}

    public String getjogadores(){return jogadores;}

    public void setjogadores(String jogadores){this.jogadores = jogadores;}

    public int getValorUm(){return valorUm;}

    public void setValorUm(int valorUm){this.valorUm = valorUm;}

    public int getValorDois(){return valorDois;}

    public void setValorDois(int valorDois){this.valorDois = valorDois;}

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nomeTimeUm+ " X " +nomeTimeDois+
                " = " +valorUm+ " X " +valorDois + " -- " +jogadores;
    }

}
```

mas creio que devo pegar a ultimo resultado que gravei no banco e compartilhar... pois se seu pegar o `nomeTimeUm`, `nomeTimeDois`, `valorUm` e `valorDois`, ele vai pegar todos que existe no banco... como que eu faria isso

OBS: Esporte é meu `get` e `set` do banco de dados

Obrigado...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você dar o `toString()` na variável `message`, por exemplo

```
Esporte objeto = ... recuperar as informações...
String message = objeto.ToString();
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui... obrigado